# lightbox plugin top_up-min.js not working with latest Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, popup

We are currently using the top_up-min.js in our website to play the videos. Recently we upgraded our JQuery version to jQuery JavaScript Library v1.8.0 with jQuery Migrate - v1.2.1 .

Since then I am getting the below script error

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .top_up,[toptions],

When I downloaded the plugin  it comes with Jquery 1.4.2 .Does anybody came across this situation ... is there any work around for this.
http://gettopup.com/examples